# facebook box_count doesn't work

Tags: facebook

I've created a Box Count in Facebook Developers page, but the count is always in 0, and the facebook page has likes....

The URL of the box count is: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/follow.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FartesanatoEraUmaVez&layout=box_count&show_faces=true&width=450&app_id=100541743441397&locale=pt_PT&sdk=joey&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D18%23cb%3Df39d850ef%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fartesanatoeraumavez.com%252Ff2199292d4%26domain%3Dartesanatoeraumavez.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent

Is this a simple issue of caching on Facebook's part? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a like box. That's a subscribe/follow button.
For a facebook page or a website you should use the like button with a box_count layout or a like box
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/